# main.c:14:10: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token what could be the issue?

Tags: c

Why am I getting this error? I'm fairly new to C just wondering what could have happened. Getting this error mainly main.c:14:10: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘=’ token. Tried fixing the error to no avail. When I remove the '-1' after int code, it compiles but not what I want it to compile. Thanks again.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct event {
    int code = -1;
    char name[50];
    int count;
    char gender;
} event[100];

int check(int code, int eventnum)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (code < 0 || code > 99)
    {
        printf("Invalid code entered.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (i <= eventnum)
    {
        if (event[i].code == code)
        {
            printf("Event with code %d already exist\n", code);
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

}

int checkcount(int count)
{
    if (count < 10 || count > 99)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of player\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int checkgender(char gender)
{
    if (gender != 'M' && gender == 'F' && gender == 'X')
    {
        printf("Invalid gender\n");
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int eventnum = -1;
    char choice;
    int code, count, i, flag;
    char gender;
    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter operation code:");
        scanf("%c", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'i':

            if (eventnum == 99)
            {
                printf("Input limit reached\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("Enter the event code:");
            scanf("%d", &code);
            if (!check(code, eventnum + 1))
                break;
            printf("Enter event name:");

            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(event[eventnum + 1].name, 49, stdin);
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("Enter number of competiters:");
            scanf("%d", &count);
            if (!checkcount(count))
                break;

            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter the gender:");
            scanf("%c", &gender);
            if (!checkgender(gender))
                break;

            fflush(stdin);

            eventnum++;
            event[eventnum].code = code;
            event[eventnum].count = count;
            event[eventnum].gender = gender;
            break;

        case 's':

            i = 0;
            flag = 0;
            printf("Enter event code:");
            scanf("%d", &code);

            while (event[i].code != code)
            {
                i++;

            }
            if (event[i].code == code)
                flag++;
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                printf("Event with code %d not found.\n", code);
            }
            printf("CODE\tEVENT NAME\tCOMPETITORS\tGENDER\n");
            printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%c\n", event[i].code,
                   event[i].name, event[i].count, event[i].gender);
            break;

        case 'u':

            i = 0;
            flag = 0;
            printf("Enter event code:");
            scanf("%d", &code);
            while (event[i].code != code)
            {
                i++;

            }
            if (event[i].code == code)
                flag++;
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                printf("Event with code %d not found.\n", code);
            }
            printf("Enter event name:");

            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(event[eventnum + 1].name, 49, stdin);

            fflush(stdin);

            printf("Enter Number of competitors:");
            scanf("%d", &count);
            if (!checkcount(count))
                break;

            fflush(stdin);

            printf("Enter gender:");

            scanf("%c", &gender);

            fflush(stdin);

            if (!checkgender(gender))
                break;
            event[i].count = count;
            event[i].gender = gender;
            break;

        case 'p':
            i = 0;
            printf("CODE\tEVENT NAME\t\t\tCOMPETITORS\tGENDER\n");
            while (i <= eventnum)
            {

                printf("%d\t%-49s\t%d\t\t%c\n",
                       event[i].code, event[i].name,
                       event[i].count, event[i].gender);
                i++;
            }
            break;

        case 'q':
            exit(0);

        default:
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) This code does not generate the given error 2) indent your code properly

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages.  More urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  If your error is on line 14, anything after that is irrelevant (but you need  a little more code than that).  Line 14 doesn't have the `-1` you reference in your description; is the code you show the same as the code you compile.

Comment: Your `checkcount()` and `checkgender()` functions don't always return a value; that's bad, but not directly the cause of your compilation problem.

Comment: The code has just been edited so that line 6 (not 14) contains `int code = -1;` inside a structure.  You can't put an initializer inside a structure definition — the `=` is invalid, just as the compiler said.  You have to remove the `= -1`.  It isn't clear what you expect it to do, but when you you define a variable of type `struct event`, you will have to ensure that `code` is initialized to `-1` by another mechanism than trying to put the initializer in the structure definition.

Answer (score 0):

The critical issue is that the code is trying to define the `event` struct, but also somehow use it as a variable at the same time.  C just doesn't work like that.

The code needs to first define what the structure is, and then secondly  declare a variable that *uses the definition*.

Also it's not legal to define values for the structure to take inside the structure definition.  This has to be done later.  This is what is causing the error you see:

```
# gcc -g -Wall yourcode.c -o yourcode.exe
yourcode.c:5:11: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
  int code = -1;
```

Perhaps you wanted something like:

```
struct event
{
    int  code;
    char name[50];
    int  count;
    char gender;
};

// Global array of event structs
#define MAX_EVENTS 100
struct event all_events[MAX_EVENTS];

// Initialise global events to "empty"
void initialiseEvents()
{
     for (int i=0; i<MAX_EVENTS; i++)
     {
          all_events[i].code    = -1;
          all_events[i].name[0] = '\0';
          all_events[i].count   = 0;
          all_events[i].gender  = '-';
     }
}
```

Here I've created a global variable `all_events`, which is an array of 100 `struct event`.  This seems to to be the intention (I guess) of the existing code.  I also added the function `initialiseEvents()` to loop through each `event` in `all_events` and set the values as per the original code (with a pinch of guesswork too).

Then the rest of the code keeps referring to the ill-defined "event" as if it's a variable, rather than a definition.  Here you need to reference the variable using the type.  Following my changes above, this would now be `all_events`.

Below is your code with these changes applied.  Please compare it to your existing.  It compiles OK, but I did not debug it further.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct event
{
    int  code;
    char name[50];
    int  count;
    char gender;
};

// Global array of event structs
#define MAX_EVENTS 100
struct event all_events[MAX_EVENTS];

int check(int code, int eventnum)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (code < 0 || code > 99)
    {
        printf("Invalid code entered.\n");
        return 0;
    }
    while (i <= eventnum)
    {
        if (all_events[i].code == code)
        {
            printf("Event with code %d already exist\n", code);
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 1;
}

int checkcount(int count)
{
    if (count < 10 || count > 99)
    {
        printf("Invalid number of player\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int checkgender(char gender)
{
    if (gender != 'M' && gender == 'F' && gender == 'X')
    {
        printf("Invalid gender\n");
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

// Initialise global events to "empty"
void initialiseEvents()
{
     for (int i=0; i<MAX_EVENTS; i++)
     {
          all_events[i].code    = -1;
          all_events[i].name[0] = '\0';
          all_events[i].count   = 0;
          all_events[i].gender  = '-';
     }
}


int main()
{

    int eventnum = -1;
    char choice;
    int code, count, i, flag;
    char gender;

    initialiseEvents();

    while (1)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter operation code:");
        scanf("%c", &choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 'i':

            if (eventnum == 99)
            {
                printf("Input limit reached\n");
                break;
            }
            printf("Enter the event code:");
            scanf("%d", &code);
            if (!check(code, eventnum + 1))
                break;
            printf("Enter event name:");

            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(all_events[eventnum + 1].name, 49, stdin);
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("Enter number of competiters:");
            scanf("%d", &count);
            if (!checkcount(count))
                break;

            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Enter the gender:");
            scanf("%c", &gender);
            if (!checkgender(gender))
                break;

            fflush(stdin);

            eventnum++;
            all_events[eventnum].code = code;
            all_events[eventnum].count = count;
            all_events[eventnum].gender = gender;
            break;

        case 's':

            i = 0;
            flag = 0;
            printf("Enter event code:");
            scanf("%d", &code);

            while (all_events[i].code != code)
            {
                i++;

            }
            if (all_events[i].code == code)
                flag++;
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                printf("Event with code %d not found.\n", code);
            }
            printf("CODE\tEVENT NAME\tCOMPETITORS\tGENDER\n");
            printf("%d\t\t%s\t\t%d\t\t%c\n", all_events[i].code,
                   all_events[i].name, all_events[i].count, all_events[i].gender);
            break;

        case 'u':

            i = 0;
            flag = 0;
            printf("Enter event code:");
            scanf("%d", &code);
            while (all_events[i].code != code)
            {
                i++;

            }
            if (all_events[i].code == code)
                flag++;
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                printf("Event with code %d not found.\n", code);
            }
            printf("Enter event name:");

            fflush(stdin);
            fgets(all_events[eventnum + 1].name, 49, stdin);

            fflush(stdin);

            printf("Enter Number of competitors:");
            scanf("%d", &count);
            if (!checkcount(count))
                break;

            fflush(stdin);

            printf("Enter gender:");

            scanf("%c", &gender);

            fflush(stdin);

            if (!checkgender(gender))
                break;
            all_events[i].count = count;
            all_events[i].gender = gender;
            break;

        case 'p':
            i = 0;
            printf("CODE\tEVENT NAME\t\t\tCOMPETITORS\tGENDER\n");
            while (i <= eventnum)
            {

                printf("%d\t%-49s\t%d\t\t%c\n",
                       all_events[i].code, all_events[i].name,
                       all_events[i].count, all_events[i].gender);
                i++;
            }
            break;

        case 'q':
            exit(0);

        default:
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```